# Querying datasets vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm working with an external access database (.accdb) in VB.NET and I'm trying to limit the amount of times that my [Winforms] program pings the data since it slows it down pretty considerably. I figured I could do this by querying my in-memory dataset instead of continuously going back to the database itself. Though, unfortunately, I cannot seem to figure out how to query my in-memory dataset. I tried looking up LINQ but couldn't find any instructions on how to set it up.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks so much! My starting code below...

```
 locsql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1)
 Dim objAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(locsql, objconn)
 objAdapter.Fill(locdata, "BASE")
```

So I can easily do some basic things I need with `locdata("BASE").rows.item("Item")` but I have to do some stuff like 
`SELECT thing FROM TABLE1 WHERE this = this and that = that` and I would just rather not keep going back to the database if possible.

Is it possible?

Comment: see this msdn link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was breaking down my data filters and creating new tables based on a series of loops and if/else statements. all of these responses were very helpful, just didn't seem to work for what I needed. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `Select` method on each datatable you want to query. The syntax is very similar to the part after the WHERE clause in you normal SQL query.  IE

```
locdata.tables(0).Select("ID = 47")
```

This returns an array of datarows.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Linq against a DataTable you need to apply the AsEnumerable method then apply the usual Linq methods.

For example.

If you need to find all the customers having the Field `Country` equals to 'Canada' and then Sum the total of their `Amount` column you could write

```
Dim listOfCanadians = locdata.Tables(0).AsEnumerable() _ 
                      .Where(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("Country") = "Canada") _ 
                      .ToList()
Dim totalCanadaAmount = listOfCanadians.Sum(Function(row) row.Field(Of Decimal)("Amount"))
```